# Getting error when run spark-shell in CDH 5.7

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am new in Spark and using CDH-5.7 for running Spark, But I am getting these error when I run Spark-shell in terminal , I have run all Cloudera Services including Spark also by Launch Cloudera Express. Plz help.

```
Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_67) 
Type in expressions to have them evaluated. Type :help for more information.
16/07/13 02:14:53 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, quickstart.cloudera resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.44.133 instead (on interface eth1) 
16/07/13 02:14:53 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
16/07/13 02:19:28 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=cloudera, access=WRITE, inode="/user/spark/applicationHistory":spark:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:281)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:262)
```

Comment: Looks like permission issue. Try sudo su.

Comment: No its not working,same error.

Comment: I was able to start spark-shell right out of the box. http://imgur.com/Tbc4aEz Try and download a new image from Cloudera.

Comment: As @morfious902002 mentioned, it is a permission issue. It seems like Spark's applicationHistory does not have enough permissions. You can try providing permissions like so - sudo -u spark hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/spark/applicationHistory